# Wordpress - WooCommerce - Change cart URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, path, routes

Is it possible to change **cart** URL (domainName/cart) that it will get the name of the product that is in the order. It is possible to order only one product and this feature is already done)
domainName/cart/nameOfTheProductThatIsInOrder

Comment: Can you please post your code, whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: I was searching files to find out which file is responsible for some kind of routing, but unfortunately I couldn't find one. I guess maybe I should write some rewrite rule.